# XSLT 2.0 deleting a sibling node based on position and name

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have the following which appears at times in an xml file (namespace tei):

```
<tei:p>some text</tei:p><tei:add>some note</tei:add>
```

My objective is to delete `<add/>` ONLY when it is the next sibling AFTER `<p>`, and not other `<add/>` elements that may appear in the file.

I've tried this in XSLT 2.0, but to no effect:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:add[preceding-sibling::node()[1][local-name()='p']]"/>
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: For the XML snippet you have shown, the template match should work ( See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBtV ). However, one reason it might not get a match is that if you have a white space node (like a new line) between the `p` and the `add`.

Comment: Ah, yes, possibly a new line problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code sample you have shown should work, but only if there is no whitespace (such as a new line) between `p` and `add` (because text counts as nodes too)

If you can have a whitespace node between them, which you want to ignore, one solution is to strip whitespace only nodes from the XML, by using `strip-space` in your XSLT

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
```

Alternatively, you can change your template match to account for whitespace nodes

```
 <xsl:template match="tei:add[preceding-sibling::node()[self::* or normalize-space()][1][local-name()='p']]"/>
```

You could potentially change it to this, if you could never have a non-whitespace node between them

```
<xsl:template match="tei:add[preceding-sibling::*[1][local-name()='p']]"/>
```